# Aliases not work to provide 2 instances of one table

Tags: sql, left-join, metabase

I am trying to pull both shipper and consignee from one table by using aliases but only shipper is working, not sure what I need to do. below is the code I am using with the joins

```
SELECT 'b_id'as 'reference_identifier'
,`Order`.`carrierBookingNum` as 'reference_number'
,`Orgc`.`code` as 'carrier_scac'
,''as'operating_carrier_scac'
,''as'auto_create_pickup'
,`Shipper`.`address`as'pickup_address_line'
, `Shipper`.`companyName`as'pickup_location'
,`Shipper`.`city`as'pickup_city'
,`Shipper`.`country`as'pickup_country'
,`Consignee`.`address`as'delivery_address_line'
, `Consignee`.`companyName` as'delivery_location'
,`Consignee`.`city`as'delivery_city'
,`Consignee`.`country`as'delivery_country'

FROM `Order`
left join `ShipmentListView` `ShipmentListView` on   `Order`.id =`ShipmentListView`.`order_id`
left join `ShipmentTag` `ShipmentTag` on `Order`.id = `ShipmentTag`.`orderId`
left join `OrgDefaultShipmentTag` `OrgDefaultShipmentTag` on `ShipmentTag`.`orgDefaultShipmentTagId`=`OrgDefaultShipmentTag`.`id`
 left JOIN `QuoteCriteria` `Quotecriteria` ON `Order`.id = `Quotecriteria`.`orderId`
left JOIN `Org` `Orgc` ON `ShipmentListView`.`quoteCriteria_carrierId` = `Orgc`.`id`
left JOIN `Person` `Person` ON `Order`.`creatorId` = `Person`.`id`
left JOIN `OrderWorkgroup` `OrderWorkgroup` on `Order`.id = `OrderWorkgroup`.`orderId`
Right join `Workgroup` `Workgroup` ON `OrderWorkgroup`.`workgroupId` = `Workgroup`.`id` and `Workgroup`.`folder`='FREIGHT FORWARDERS'
left JOIN `OrderContacts` `Ordercontacts` ON `Order`.`id` = `Ordercontacts`.`orderId`
left JOIN `Contact` `Consignee` ON `Ordercontacts`.`contactId`= `Consignee`.`id` and `Ordercontacts`.`type` = 'Consignee'
left JOIN `Contact` `Shipper` ON `Ordercontacts`.`contactId`= `Shipper`.`id` and `Ordercontacts`.`type` = 'Shipper'
```

I tried to use aliases and was expecting to see Shipper and consignee details based on the joins

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Code ref to you trying to pull both the `shipper` and `consignee` details from the `Contact table` by using `aliases` and joining it twice with the `OrderContacts` table looks *ok*.

- You may want to check if there are *any rows* in the `OrderContacts table` with a type value of `'Consignee'.` If there are no rows with this value, then the join condition `Ordercontacts.contactId= Consignee.id and Ordercontacts.type = 'Consignee'` will not return any rows
- Also  try running each `join` separately to see if the issue is with a specific join or if it is with the overall query.
- Another thing - try using a `subquery` to pull the `shipper` and `consignee` details separately before joining them with the rest of your query.

Comment: Thank you I tried subquery, with below it only returns shipper. If I make the join on consignee line just Join it only shows the consignee. If I make both just join nothing comes up?

FROM `OrderContacts`
left JOIN `Contact` AS `Consignee` ON `OrderContacts`.`contactId` = `Consignee`.`id` and `OrderContacts`.`type` = 'consignee'
left JOIN `Contact` AS `Shipper` ON `OrderContacts`.`contactId` = `Shipper`.`id` and `OrderContacts`.`type` = 'shipper'
WHERE `OrderContacts`.`orderId` = '508715'
group by `orderId`

Comment: diff to write stuff in comment box https://paste.c-net.org/BarbecueUgliest  open that tell me what you see  for each